# What is a fast way to convert a string date to a number?

Tags: r

I have a lot of large csv files (several MB), with a lot of numbers and times, where all values are stored without quotation marks, and separated by semicolons. Numbers are encoded with colons for decimal separators. Times are encoded as hh:mm:ss. Many values are missing, and they are encoded as string with size zero (not "NA").

I need to convert strings representing numbers to numbers, and times to some numerical representation, that would allow easy arithmetic operations. AFAIK the default date/time representation in R is quite bulky, the POSIXct object on my system is 312 bytes long.

I use a piece of code like this:

```
library(chron) #For chron function
library(plyr)

string2time<-function(f)
{
  if(is.na(f))
  {
    return(NA)
  }
  if(f==''){
    return(NA)
  } 
  n<-as.numeric(f)
  if(is.na(n))
  {
    ans<-n
    try(ans<-chron(times.=f),
        silent=TRUE)
    return(as.numeric(ans))
  }
  return(n)
}

interpreteCSV<-function(filename,parallel)
{
   data<-read.csv2(filename)
   data.fix<-t(laply(data,function(x) {aaply(as.character(x),1,string2time)},.parallel=parallel))
   return(data.fix)
}
```

The problem is that the function is seems very inefficient.

I know, that the function looks awkward, but it is a that it is the only that works with the missing values. Maybe I could speed it up a little, if I wrote two functions: one for numeric columns, and the other for times columns. But something tells me, that I'm missing here something fundamental here, and that's why I ask you for some inspiration.

Here is a profiling excerpt:

```
> ?Rprof
> summaryRprof(filename="/tmp/temp/rprof.out")
$by.self
                           self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
".Call"                         0.30    93.75       0.30     93.75
"getIterVal.containeriter"      0.02     6.25       0.02      6.25

$by.total
                           total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"<Anonymous>"                    0.32    100.00      0.00     0.00
"a_ply"                          0.32    100.00      0.00     0.00
"%dopar%"                        0.32    100.00      0.00     0.00
"l_ply"                          0.32    100.00      0.00     0.00
"prepare.rds.from.csv"           0.32    100.00      0.00     0.00
".Call"                          0.30     93.75      0.30    93.75
"mclapply"                       0.30     93.75      0.00     0.00
"FUN"                            0.16     50.00      0.00     0.00
"lapply"                         0.16     50.00      0.00     0.00
"selectChildren"                 0.16     50.00      0.00     0.00
```

A sample line of csv looks like that (excluding the header). There are several thousand such lines in the file:

```
1;XAD-01;m;wn;18,00;6;7;6;60;;;;15:10:11.8;;2,73;;16,56;;15:10:19.4;;15:10:11.8;;15:10:23.9;;15:10:19.4;;15:10:28.6;;0;;0;;0;;0;;15:10:06.0;;59,70;;15:10:36.6;;-1,47;;617;;0;;3,65;;29,96;;15:10:33.4;;15,97;;15:10:33.4;;4,43;5;12;4;30;8;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Comment: Please show a small example dataframe!

Comment: You appear to be confused about R date storage modes. A single POSIXct element should be an 8 byte double (number of seconds since origin). Presumably you know which columns are date-times. You should include this information. (It's trivial to convert length zero character elements to NA_character_ values.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you know which column numbers need conversion. Further assume this set of columns is in a vector named `cols.to,convert`:

```
cols.to.convert <-  grep( "\\d{1,2}\\:\\d{1,2}\\:\\d{1,2}", dfrm[1,])
cols.to.convert
# [1] 13 19 21 23 25 27 37 41 53 57

dfrm[cols.to.convert]  <- lapply(dfrm[cols.to.convert], as.POSIXct, format="%H:%M:%S")

# all now POSIXct class.
lapply(dfrm[cols.to.convert], class)
```

Note that an R `POSIXct` vector will have both a date and a time and by default converting from a time-only format will return a date-time with today's date:

```
> dfrm$V57
[1] "2014-01-12 15:10:33 PST"
```

Then for the NA conversion this should be fairly efficient:

```
  is.na(dfrm) <- dfrm = =""
```

Comment: Yes, it did a lot of speed up. Hundreds of times. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have found the `melt` function in reshape2 to be a major contribution to R functionality, but I have not found the rest of the reshape2/ply2 additions to be helpful. My opinion may be colored by the fact that I have always been working with large datasets. Both the reshape2/plyr combo and the data.table package have altered syntaxes that represent a conceptual hurdle for me in using them. The speed and size benefits of 'data.table' made it worthwhile for me to learn that package's syntax, while the diminished speed of the 'plyr' functions made it unproductive of me to commit it to memory.

Comment: I read that there will be a son-of-plyr package that has speed as a design target.

Comment: I never heard of the `data.table` package. Thank you very much for the tip!